# ¿Cómo colocar un país por defecto en MapBox en Android Studio?

Tags: java, android

Intento implementar mi país por defecto, pero la búsqueda es limitada, no encuentra en la búsqueda lugares muy populares tal como lo hace Google

```
Intent intent = new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder()
      .accessToken(Mapbox.getAccessToken() != null ? Mapbox.getAccessToken() : getString(R.string.mapbox_access_token))
      .placeOptions(PlaceOptions.builder()
      .backgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#EEEEEE"))
      .limit(10)
      .country("PE")
      .build(PlaceOptions.MODE_CARDS))
      .build(getActivity());
      startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_AUTOCOMPLETE);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hay dos opciones para cargar un paìs por defecto, puedes definir en tu vista los valores de geolocalizaciòn del paìs que deseas especificar como predeterminado al cargar el mapa:

```
<com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    mapbox:mapbox_cameraTargetLat="14.640720"
    mapbox:mapbox_cameraTargetLng="-90.513270"
    mapbox:mapbox_cameraZoom="5.526846"/>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Programaticamente puedes mover la camara a las coordenadas del paìs que deseas, en ambas opciones puedes definir un zoom adecuado.

```
    mapView = findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(@NonNull final MapboxMap mapboxMap) {

            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .target(new LatLng(14.640720, -90.513270))
                    .zoom(10) // Sets the zoom
                    .bearing(180) // Rotate the camera 180 degrees
                    .tilt(30) // Set the camera tilt
                    .build(); // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder

            mapboxMap.setCameraPosition(cameraPosition);

   });
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]